# .htaccess parsing a phone number

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering if anyone could help me with an htaccess rule.

I have a phone directory, and the folders are based on the phone number i.e. http://example.com/go/123-456-7890. But I'm finding a lot of users are refusing to use dashes and get an error message. I was wondering if there is a simple way to parse that with htaccess so they get automatically redirected to the right url format?

i.e. if they type http://example.com/go/1234567890 or http://example.com/go/(123)456-7890 that they get moved to http://example.com/go/123-456-7890

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4}) /go/$1-$2-$3 [R]
```

This only does solid numbers - I am not great @ mod_rewrite but this is a start:)

Answer (score 0):

These 2 rules in your root .htaccess should take care of that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(go)/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/?$ /$1/$2-$3-$4 [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(go)/\((\d{3})\)(\d{3}-\d{4})/?$ /$1/$2-$3 [L,NC,R=302]
```